# Различия между гибридным, нативным и веб приложениями

Tags: android, ios, веб-программирование, мобильная-разработка, windowsphone

В чем различия между гибридным, нативным и веб приложениями?

Answer (score 5):

В случае мобильной разработки:

1. Web-приложение - это, по сути, просто сайт. То есть само приложение состоит из внутреннего браузера, который всегда при старте открывает определенный сайт из интернета. То есть нет никакой разницы: открывать страницу в Safari/Chrome, или же использовать приложение.
2. Гибридное приложение содержит весь сайт сразу в себе, то есть с точки зрения пользователя оно такое же, как и просто нативное приложение. После того, как программа загрузилась из маркета, она сразу готова к работе. Более того - она может работать без интернета. Важное отличие от нативного приложения - гибридное пишется на Javascript/Webassembly, то есть на кроссплатформенных языках. И выполняется оно в "embedded browser", то есть стили в телефоне могут иногда не совпадать со стилями в приложении.

Если приводить аналоги для desktop Windows, то:

1. Нативное приложение - это Microsoft Office, Косынка, Калькулятор, Visual Studio. Для работы не требуется интернет. Более того - стили (цвета) операционной системы используются в самих приложениях
2. Web-приложение - это закладка в Chrome/IE. То есть без интернета его не запустить.
3. Гибридное приложение - это Telegram for Desktop, Visual Studio Code, Electron. Внутри всех них, на самом деле, стоит WebKit браузер, а немалая часть логики написана на Javascript, так что при отрисовке ряд стилей может не совпадать со стилями системы. Однако, с точки зрения пользователя, они ничем не отличаются от нативных приложений.